# Tkinter: Canvas create_line screen drawing math

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Does anyone have any idea how is tkinter/tcl actually drawing the line on the screen? I'm interested in actual math used to, for example, draw a line of width 9 diagonally with start point at (a,b) and end point at (c,d).

That is, without any smoothing, so with jagged edges and warts! I tried googling and finding this info in tcl docs, but to no avail.

Here's what I noticed by using the magnifier tool to see pixels clearly: line of width 1 just follows the mouse motion when drawing it. Width 2 adds pixels with an offset of -1 to the width 1 line (now this depends on the line direction, so it can mean either to the left of mouse motion, or below it). Width 3 adds pixels with an offset of +1 (right/above mouse motion) to the pixels of line with width 2. Etc. But I have absolutely no idea what calculations tkinter/tcl is doing for diagonals.

I need this info to be precise, so that I know exactly which pixels are being influenced on the canvas (which holds an image in the background, so I'm using create_line to actually form a mask for selecting pixels that are going to be influenced in some way).

Comment: Have you considered simply looking at the source code? it's publicly available.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea, but I have no idea where to look for that specific part... I run 64-bit Anaconda Python v3 on W7 x64... Looking into the tcl folder, I can't find a file called canvas.tcl (whereas there are files called menu.tcl, button.tcl, spinbox.tcl, and so on). Confusing!

Comment: I am guessing that tk uses something similar to the least squares method to find the closest pixels to the line.

Comment: @MarioKrušelj: you won't find it in tcl or python code. It's written in C. It looks like it boils down to a call of XDrawLines from XLib. I don't know what algorithm it uses.  There's a good chance it uses Bresenham's line algorithm, but I don't know that for certain.

Comment: Thanks for that info! Much obliged.

Comment: all i could find was: [here](https://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/c8e79a56ab9db93c)                                                                                                                                                           
int
XDrawLine(
    Display *display,
    Drawable d,
    GC gc,
    int x1, int y1,
    int x2, int y2)
{
    XPoint points[2];
    points[0].x = x1;points[0].y = y1;points[1].x = x2;points[1].y = y2;
    return XDrawLines(display, d, gc, points, 2, CoordModeOrigin);
}